# How to hide and show sidenavbar in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying show and hide navbars in angular 2 but this is not working right now,
my temmplate,

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom:0px !important;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a id="menu-toggle" (click)="show()" class="navbar-toggle">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.xhtml">
        <img src="images/socialwiki.png">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div  *ngIf="hide" id="sidebar-wrapper"  class="sidebar-toggle">

      <ul class="sidebar-nav">
         <li>
              <a onclick="profilelink('login')"><i class="icon-signin"></i>login</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a onclick="profilelink('profile')"><i class="iconwidth icon-user"></i>Profile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a onclick="profilelink('socialaddress')">Social Address<i class="icon-share"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a onclick="profilelink('custominfo')"><i class="icon-info-sign"></i>Custom Info</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a onclick="profilelink('mysociety')"><i class="icon-users"></i>My Society(All)</a>

          </li>
          <li>
              <a onclick="profilelink('myprofile')"><i class="iconwidth icon-user"></i>My Profile</a>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

My ts,

```
 export class Navbar {
hide:any = false;
show():any{
    alert("hi");
    this.hide = true;
}
```

I am getting the alert message but unable to show the side bar,can someone suggest help please..................

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. Are you sure the sidebar isn't being inserted, but maybe isn't visible because of some css issue? Another possibility is that you're using ChangeDetection.OnPush?

Comment: Flip Lauc,whats change detection ?

Comment: Here is a great blog post on the subject http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html

Comment: Thats good but i dont think that make a sense

Comment: You are right,when i remove id appended to it,then it displays...........

Comment: glad you got it solved :)